# How to merge two image from edges to look like a single image in iOS?

Tags: ios7, cgcontext

I have two imageview. How can i merge this image so it will look like a single image. I tried a lot like creating blur and gradient at the end of first image and at the start of second image even though not getting desired result like below image.

This is normal image.

[image]

and this after merging.

[image]

How to achieve this result? Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both images must be blurred on the edge. Images should overlap. One of those images should have alpha-gradient on the overlapping area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer. Use below code and add gradient mask to both images at border. You can shift some pixel of second image view frame upper to first image, so the first image view border and second image view border will merge completely.

```
-(void)addGradientTo:(UIImageView*)imageView {

CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = imageView.bounds;

gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.2] CGColor],
                            (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:1] CGColor],
                            (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:1] CGColor],
                            (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.2] CGColor], nil];

gradient.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0],
                      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:.1],
                      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:.9],
                      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1], nil];

gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0,0.3);
gradient.endPoint=CGPointMake(1,0.3);
[imageView.layer setMask:gradient];
```

}

Comment: Can you please tell me how did you merge the two images like you did??